# Check if an array of arrays contains a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, include

I know that if there is an array of values it must be used this approach:

```
console.log(['joe', 'jane', 'mary'].includes('jane')); // true
```

But in case of an array of arrays, is there a short way to do it? Without other computations between.

For this input:

```
[['jane'],['joe'],['mary']]
```

Comment: `arr.some((a) => a.includes("jane"));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use flat method to flatten the array. For more neted array, you can also mention depth like flat(depth)

```
let arr = [["jane"],["joe"],["mary"]];

arr.flat().includes('jane'); //true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve this result using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
arr.some((a) => a.includes("jane"))
```

```js
const arr = [
  ["jane"],
  ["joe"],
  ["mary"]
];
const arr2 = [
  ["joe"],
  ["mary"]
];

console.log(arr.some((a) => a.includes("jane")));
console.log(arr2.some((a) => a.includes("jane")));
```

Answer (score 0):

it can also be done by first flattening the 2d arrays in 1 d aaray and then using includes to find whether the array contains the element or not

```
var arr = [['jane'],['joe'],['marry']]
var newarr=[].concat(...arr)
var v=newarr.includes('jane')
console.log(v)
```